# Mac Terminal shows "Ä" and "Å" characters instead of square or curly brackets

Tags: macos, terminal

In my terminal, it is showing "Ä" and "Å" instead of {, }, [, and ].

[image: terminal screenshot]

I'm on OS X Monterey. It also looks like backticks are displaying as "é".

[image]

Comment: In Terminal->Preferences->Profile what font have you chosen?

Comment: More likely to be a Unicode encoding mismatch. But I don't know how you'd fix that in Terminal. If you copy the text to something like BBEdit or TextEdit, is it correct?

Comment: Are those things you are typing?  What language keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @mmmmmm in Terminal -> Profile I see it's using UTF-8 Text encoding

Comment: @benwiggy if I copy paste the text into TextEdit, it still shows those Ä characters

Comment: @TomGewecke this is output from the Terminal, it's Rust (with the Cargo compiler, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Can you pipe the output to `xxd` (or some other hexdump program) to see what bytes are being used to encode those characters?

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` show?

Comment: I have this same issue. @Benji what are you using to print that output? For me it's Python 3.10. I'm going to try playing with the encoding of the file itself.